# Django Modelformset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have followed this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/ to help me in creating a modelformset. However, each time I press "submit", it creates new forms and it shows the previously submitted forms. That's not what I want, I want to specify in my view how many forms I want and it should stay that way after submitting. How can I cause no extra forms to be made after submitting?

**views.py:**

```
def test(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name', 'title', 'birth_date'), extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render(request, 'voting/test.html', {'formset': formset})
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet()
    return render(request, 'voting/test.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**models.py:**

```
TITLE_CHOICES = [
    ('MR', 'Mr.'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
    ('MS', 'Ms.'),
]

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py:**

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
```

**test.html:**

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_data }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset }}
    <button type="submit" name = "voting" class="btn btn-primary save">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: To prevent the creation of new forms after submitting, you can set the `extra` parameter in `modelformset_factory` to `0` so it should be `AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name', 'title', 'birth_date'), extra=0)`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey hello, if I do this, then no form is shown on my test.html page, so there is only the submit button. How can I now say I want to have 2 forms for example?

Comment: Also set `can_delete=True` so `AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, form=AuthorForm, fields=('name', 'title', 'birth_date'), extra=1, can_delete=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I now say I want to have 2 forms for example?

If you set `extra` parameter to `0` while creating the `formset`, then no extra forms will be displayed initially. To display a specific number of forms, you can pass an empty queryset to the formset's constructor and then use the `extra` parameter to specify how many extra forms to display.

Use the following view to display 2 forms:

```py
def test(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, form=AuthorForm, fields=('name', 'title', 'birth_date'), extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render(request, 'voting/test.html', {'formset': formset})
    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet(queryset=Author.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'voting/test.html', {'formset': formset})
```

In the template, the formset will be displayed using `{{ formset }}`, which will display the two forms.